# React Hooks - How to target an element child (with useRef) with a variable declaration outside of useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm experimenting with React Hooks and I'm wondering how to target elements children with useRef. Actually, I know how to target an element with useRef. But I meet some problems when I'm trying to assign children to a variable.

Here's an example :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let containerRef = useRef(null);

  let title, subtitle;

  const myEvent = () => {
    console.log(title);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    title = containerRef.children[0];
    subtitle = containerRef.children[1];
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={el => (containerRef = el)}>
      <h1 onClick={myEvent}>Hello World!</h1>
      <h2>What's going on ?</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like to access to the title and subtitle variables to create a function **outside of useEffect**. I know I'm wrong about the first declaration of *title* and *subtitle*. But actually I don't know how to fix this. I tried to use **useState**, but I failed to resolve my problem.

(Precisions : of course, in my real project, I just don't want display the variable in the console).

Can someone help me to fix this ?

Comment: Just a note: you are using a mix of the old way of defining a ref and a the way. If you are using `useRef` you don't need to pass a function to `ref` prop. Just `ref=containerRef`

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are doing this inside a `useEffect`. Why you can't simply get the `title` or whatever in the function scope? You are trying to cache for performance?

Comment: Hey Keul, thanks for your comment. I don't declare the title variable inside the function because in my real project, I need to re-use this variable, and I don't know to re-write this. Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to target your `current` HTML element and then get children like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const myEvent = () => {
    console.log(title);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(containerRef.current.children[0]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={containerRef}>
      <h1 onClick={myEvent}>Hello World!</h1>
      <h2>What's going on ?</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will log children to the console. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey Muhammad, thanks for your comment. Actually, I don't have a problem to display the title or the container in the console. My problem is just about the variable declaration. I need to declare the variable outside of my event function because I need to use it in another function (in my real project).

Comment: Answer Updated. You can just clean the text.

Comment: Aditionally, if you need to access deper children, use: `.children[n].children[n]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use useRef to store some object between renders:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const titleRef = useRef(null);
  const subtitleRef = useRef(null);

  const myEvent = () => {
    console.log(titleRef.current);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    titleRef.current = containerRef.current.children[0];
    subtitleRef.current = containerRef.current.children[1];
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={containerRef}>
      <h1 onClick={myEvent}>Hello World!</h1>
      <h2>What's going on ?</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sound-e0eq2

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is what I needed !

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to access a child using the name attribute instead of the index; you could do it the following way:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let containerRef = useRef(null);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const myEvent = () => {
    console.log(title);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(containerRef.current.children['element_name_attribute']);
    //OR:
    setTitle(containerRef.current.children.element_name_attribute);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={containerRef}>
      <h1 name="element_name_attribute" onClick={myEvent}>Hello World!</h1>
      <h2>What's going on ?</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```