# TS2339: Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I understand optional chaining should be enough but I have gone a bit overboard here to try satisfy TypeScript:

```
const ref = useRef()

    if (ref !== undefined) {
        if(ref.hasOwnProperty('current')) {
            if (ref.current !== undefined &&  ref.current !== null)
             console.log(ref?.current?.getBoundingClientRect())
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
TS2339: Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

I miss my non-typing days... Any solution other than `@ts-ignore`

Comment: `ref` will always be an object, though `current` will be undefined by default. You need to use it, either within the rendering process or manually put something yourself in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks - How to target an element child (with useRef) with a variable declaration outside of useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503263/react-hooks-how-to-target-an-element-child-with-useref-with-a-variable-decla)

Comment: See also: [What typescript type do I use with useRef() hook when setting current manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58017215/1218980)

Comment: Specifically, in your case: [How to use React useRef with TypeScript](https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-use-react-useref-with-typescript)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You just have to provide an element type to useRef

```
const Test = () => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const rect = ref?.current?.getBoundingClientRect();
}
```